# Why did the question stipulate that k is prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose ${a_1,a_2,...,a_k}$ is a complete residue system modulo $k$, where $k$ is a prime.  Prove that for each integer $n$ and nonnegative integer $s$, there exists a congruence of the form
$n \equiv \sum_{j=0}^{s} b_jk^j\:(\bmod k^{s+1})$ where each of the $b_j$ is one of the $a_i$.

When exploring what the problem was getting at, I simply picked k=5 (a small k).
So clearly our $a_1,a_2,...,a_k$ are congruent to $0,1,2,3,4$. I then picked $s=0$.  So we are saying any $n$ is congruent to either $0,1,2,3$, or $4$ in mod $5$.  All good so far.  And then for $s=1$, we are saying any number $n$ is congruent mod 25 to $(b_0 + 5b_1)$ mod 25.  And this makes sense since any integer from 0 to 24 inclusive can be expressed this way.

Essentially the problem boils down to the fact that every integer is congruent to a unique number in each of mod 5, mod 25, mod 125, etc.  And that there is a base 5 representation of that.

Am I missing something?  I don't see why the problem stipulated that $k$ needed to be prime.

Comment: I assume $a_j$ and $b_j$ are supposed to be the same? I agree with you, the primality of $k$ doesn't seem to be important. (We use the case $k=10$ in daily life all the time.)

Comment: The question has a second part, where it plays then a role that $k=p$ is prime. So perhaps this is the reason. Can you give a link to the full question(s)?

Comment: Greg, I saw your comment and realized I left off the last part of the problem.  Yes, each of the $b_j$ is one of the $a_i$.  And since $s$ can be larger than $k$, we can use each $a_i$ more than once.  I added that last part to the original problem.

Comment: Hi, Dietrich.  That actually is the full problem.  No other part to it listed.  It is problem 3, Section 4-2 (Residue Systems) in Number Theory by George Andrews.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn’t need $k$ prime. When we pick the $a_i$ to be $\{0,1,\dots,k-1\},$ this amounts to writing $n$ in base $k.$ When the $a_i$ are not so nice, it is more complicated, but not hard.

Comment: Prove it by induction on $s.$

Comment: Probably because multiplicative groups on $k$ not prime partially rely on the one when $k$ is...